# how can I stop Groovy replacing multiple forward slashes with single forward slash when creating new File

Tags: java, amazon-s3, groovy

I have the following file accessed through aws S3:

`s3://ngi-igenomes/igenomes/Homo_sapiens/NCBI/GRCh38/Annotation/Genes/genes.gtf`

I have made a function that checks the contents of the file, and works fine for local files. Consider the following:

```
gtf_file_str = 's3://ngi-igenomes/igenomes/Homo_sapiens/NCBI/GRCh38/Annotation/Genes/genes.gtf'
println gtf_file_str
File gtf_file = new File(gtf_file_str)
println gtf_file
```

When executing this I get the following:

```
s3://ngi-igenomes/igenomes/Homo_sapiens/NCBI/GRCh38/Annotation/Genes/genes.gtf
s3:/ngi-igenomes/igenomes/Homo_sapiens/NCBI/GRCh38/Annotation/Genes/genes.gtf
```

My function then doesn't recognise `gtf_file` because it has gotten rid of the double forward slash and replaced it with a single. How can I stop it replacing the double forward slash?

Comment: When you write `new File`, is that `java.io.File`? In that case, the problem has nothing to do with the forward slash. It's much simpler that; File represents files on disk. You can't use a j.i.File object for this - whatever API you are handing this File ref off to probably also has something that takes an InputStream or URI or URL. That's the route forward.If it is your own function, that construct is a URI and not a File, so update your method to take a URI object instead of a File object.

Comment: I see, thank you! When I specify it as a URI the string isn't changed. However, in my function that checks the file, it uses `withReader` to go through the file line by line. I'd instead like to save the file specified by the URI to a temporary file. What should I use to save the file?

Comment: As I explained, the `File` in `java.io.File` means __file on disk__ and cannot mean anything else. Whatever it is you are trying to do will never work as long as `java.io.File` is involved. Get off that. "Copy an inputstream into a temporary file" is a simple task and I'm sure, described in many things you can find on the web.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help!